# Interval not starting under the useEffect hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**It's a experiment to know the things,**

I expect both the `setInterval` to work on start. but it's not. Need to understand `useEffect` and `setInterval` how they works and what it's stopping the `setInterval` here (2nd one not updating the value ). But I see randomly update on both.

code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [student, setStudent] = useState(0);
  const [teacher, setTeacher] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setStudent((student) => student + 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId2 = setInterval(() => {
      setTeacher((Teacher) => Teacher + 1 / 2);
    }, 2000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId2);
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p key={"0"}>Student - {student}</p>
      <p key={"1"}>Counter - {teacher}</p>
      {student === teacher ? "bother are ok" : "need more..."}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-shamir-ckhn8c?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `deps` on both of them as:

[`CODESANDBOX`](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-fast-59mhf6?file=/src/App.js)

First will work as expected because you have not given the `dependency` so it will trigger every time the component renders

But when it comes to second `useEffect` it won't work because it is getting cleared before the `2 sec` timer expires, Because you have not given the `deps` so it will get cleared every time the component renders(In your case when first `useEffect` timer expires after `1 sec`). So you have to explicitly tell `useEffect` that you have to trigger only when `teacher` changes not everytime and especially not when first `useEffect` triggers.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setStudent((student) => student + 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [student]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId2 = setInterval(() => {
      setTeacher((Teacher) => Teacher + 1 / 2);
    }, 2000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId2);
  }, [teacher]);
```